# JEST - mocking a variable (or a map result) in a method

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have a problem on the persistence lvl. I want to test the `GetService`, but I cannot mock the result of the map in `responsePromises` and I NEED to mock it, because it's a dependency from the Google Cloud.

I cannot simply use the code below, because there is a multiple GCP used:

```
jest
            .spyOn(gcpStorageServiceStub, 'read')
            .mockImplementation((bucketName: string, fileName: string): Promise<string> => Promise.resolve(JSON));
```

I want to mock const **responsePromises** (so the result of the mapping) in my test suite, how to do it?

(X,Y,Z... are json files that I download from the cloud and then read them one by one)

```
export class GetService {
  constructor(
    @inject(BINDINGS.GcpStorageService) private gcpStorageService: GcpStorageServiceInterface,
  ) {}

  @CatchError()
  async getItems(): Promise<Interface> {
    const FILES = [X, Y, Z, K, L];
    const responsePromises = FILES.map((FILE_NAME: string) => this.gcpStorageService.read(BUCKET, FILE_NAME));
    const responseJsons = await Promise.all(responsePromises);

    );
```

Comment: I was thinking about using a switch statement somehow in mockImplementation, so I could mock-read repeatedly the XYZKL variables, but not sure how to do it, any ideas?

Comment: What is the test though? Are you testing something that uses getItems, if so can you instead just mock getItems entirely? Or are you testing getItems itself and confirming certain calls to gcp are being done?

Comment: GetItems uses a lot of different services and in order to test the integration with them I need to first mock the persistence level - so the result of the mocking.